# sorting a JTable using a data vector

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I got stuck with a performance problem while writing my program and I need your help! :)

I'm using a JTable to view test results taken from a vector I made and it has 4 columns in it. When I click on a row the details from a saved txt file of that test are shown in a child window. Also, when I click on the columns header the event sends the vector to a function that sorts it according to the pressed column. Every time a new value needs to be entered the sorting function is called again.

My program works fine with a small number of rows. But, when I enter say, 150 rows, every time I enter a new row the Table flicks (the sort probably takes a lot of time), but I have to keep the vector synchronized with the jable because of the "push to view the result" option.

I would really appreciate some help with this.
thanks

Comment: The only possible reason for the flicker is that you perhaps re-create the whole model... Do you?

Comment: nop...model is created only once....  but before entering the new values i remove all the elements and fill the model with the vector again

Comment: That is exactly what I was suspecting you are doing... Yes, you do not re-create the model per-se, but you are re-creating the underlying storage object. That is a large overhead and should be avoided. Do not re-create the vector. You always add new rows to the vector via the `add()`. The JTable will sort it automatically anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JTable's internal sorter (DefaultRowSorter). Do not re-create the vector which holds the data - use Vector's add() method to add new records. In many years of Java GUI development I haven't seen a single case where I had to keep records in the TableModel sorted. Make sure getColumnClass() returns a proper type, so the default sorter knows how to sort the column, and that is all.

Comment: Remove the sorting and organising of the vector whatsoever. If you want a special sorting, make your own RowSorter implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have to do any sorting yourself. `JTable` supports sorting natively, and has the `convertRowIndexToModel` and `convertRowIndexToView` methods to go from the view index to the model index and vice-versa.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting.

Comment: thanks but i allready know that i can use the sorter of the table, but the thing is that it will sort the row without changing the vector positions and then i get a mix in the true values in the container and the ones in show

Comment: That's probably because you don't use convertRowIndexToModel and convertRowIndexToView when you need to. If you have a sorted table and have the index of the selected row, call convertRowIndexToModel to get the index of this row in the model (the vector). If you have some index in the vector and want to know which row it is in the view, use convertRowIndexToView. If the problem is elsewhere, please edit your question to make the problem clearer and show us some code which causes this problem.

Comment: +1, Also you may not even need to use the convertXXX methods. If you use table.getValueAt(...) the data is accessed in the sorted view order. If you use table.getModel().getValueAt(...) the data is accessed in the unsorted order of the model. You should not be trying to access the Vector directly.

Comment: @camickr: Most of the time, I use methods of the domain objects contained in the table model when some action is triggered on a selected row: MyDomainObject o = myTableModel.get(convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow()));

Comment: Thats fine if you have a custom TableModel with custom Objects. But the posters question is about a data Vector which indicates to me he is using the DefaultTableModel which uses a Vector of Vectors to store the data so all accesses to the data will be one cell at a time. That is why I suggested "you may not" need to use the convertXXX methods because I'm not postive about the posters usage.